# What kind of scenes can Dreamcraft be used to display?

Tags: cypher-system

For the Awakens Dream focus, how would the tier 1 ability Dreamcraft be used to display a scene?  I'm unclear as to what the "scene" could be.  Either:

a) a full on scene with objects and a different setting other than reality.  Even if my character is in a building, I could surround myself in a dream "bubble" where the ground appears to be grass, I'm surrounded by trees, and a clear blue sky overhead.  The scene could animate and move with me, so as my character moves, the trees "pass by" (by animating) as I walk through the dream.  I kind of imagine this like a Star Trek holodeck (but it would have to move with the character viewing the scene).

or b) a scene of just objects in my character's reality.  When we tested the Cypher System before starting a real campaign, our GM ran a dinner party murder story.  After the death occurred, I used Dreamcraft to place all of the characters around the dinner table before the lights went out, and recreated different scenarios as to how the murder occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say more b) than a).

Any physical interaction breaks the illusion. Such as your feet touching the grass. Bam. Shattered.

It only fills an immediate area. so the forest would abruptly end a few feet away. Perhaps in a small room the illusion could be convincing until you tried stepping on the path.

I think you certainly could make a scene surround someone. But it would have to be carefully done to avoid them breaking it.

But your murder recreations would totally work.

Comment: I suppose a) would be more reserved for the tier 4 Daydream ability then.  Thanks for the answer.